# Background job running without affecting the rest of the gui

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, event-dispatch-thread

I'm asking for assistance concerning a general approach.

I have written some java code to check my mailbox for unread mails on buttonclick.

Now I want this code to permanently run in the background and check my mailbox every 2 minutes.

Bad idea:

```
while(true)
{
checkMails();
Thread.sleep(120000);
}
```

The rest of the graphical interface obviously freezes, so there has to happen some magic with threads, I suppose.

How could this be realized?

Comment: Timer could work, but if `checkMails()` takes any significant time then your UI will hang again.

Comment: Make your own thread :D That's the best solution.

Comment: @laika, if you have your answer, accept the one that helped to you the most so others can learn where you did.

Answer (score 4):

Either use a [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html), or [`SwingWorker`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), although the latter is a bit overkill in this scenario.

---

If this task does not modify any Swing components, then why not just spawn a separate thread, as such

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
            //do stuff

            try{
                Thread.sleep(120000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
});
t.start();
```

It's important to note that you'll probably want to use a `boolean` to ensure that the thread is only created once, since there's the potential that a new thread will spawn with each button click, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for that. When doing my stuff I'm inside the Thread class, i.e. in run(). From there I can't reach checkMails. Does checkMails have to be static?

Comment: @laika, You can place this logic within `checkMails()`, if you want. Otherwise, you'll either need an instance of the object that contains this method, or as you said, you can make it a static utility method.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just spawn a seperate thread that will handle the `checkMails()` and perform that action you already have. Just be careful when you update your GUI.

```
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            while (true) {
                checkMails();
                Thread.sleep(120000);
            }
        }
    });
```

edit: Maybe you should add a check somewhere in the case you want to stop the checking for new mail (for whatever reason). Also you got to call `thread.start();`

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html). Something like this:

```
int delay = 120000;
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        checkMails();
    }
};
new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

Comment: best one, for javax.swing.Timer +1

Answer (score 1):

You need to use threading to solve this. Threads are like multitasking.

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        //do job
    }
}
t.start(); //starts the thread
```

To end the thread, you'll need some kind of stopping condition

```
public boolean run = false;
Thread t = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        while(run)
            //do job
    }
}
public void startThread(){
    t.start(); //starts the thread
}
```

See also:

- [Introduction to threads](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-1996/jw-04-threads.html)
- The Javadoc for [Thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html).

`Thread.stop()` will kill the thread, but this is very bad. For example, suppose that you're writing into an array

```
for(int i = 0; i < myAr.length; i++)
    myAr[i] = getStuff(i);
```

And at `i = 5`, `Thread.stop()` is called. Now your program thinks that everything is good, when in fact, it's not!

To kill the thread, set `run` to `false`. `run` is a `boolean` I showed in the second example. The other option is to create a subclass of `Thread` (not just in line overriding methods) and create a method `halt()` (`stop` is final). `halt()` will set `run` to false. `run` will still be a global `boolean`.

Here's an example of that.

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    public boolean run = true;
    public void run(){
        run = true;
        while(run)
            doStuff();
    }
    public void halt(){
        run = false;
    }
}
```

You need to be careful that two threads aren't modifying the same object at once, it would be like turning an object into a random number generator :/

Now that you have been given the power of threads, use it wisely, for good not for evil! Go forth and be thread-safe.

Comment: Don't try this at home kids! You need to ensure that changes to the run variable made in one thread are going to be visible to the running thread. The easiest way to do this is make run volatile.

Comment: You're saying that the issue is that if you have multiple threads running on the same `run`, you'll have issues? Sometimes that's desired. Other times, you use my 2nd solution, subclassing.

Comment: No, I'm saying that if the GUI thread (in this instance) calls halt(), setting run to false then MyThread will not necessarily stop because it may not ever see the run variable being set to false.

Comment: Tip:  If you add a '6' to a search, e.g. 'javadoc+thread+6', the top hit will be the Java 6 JavaDocs.  I edited your post to point to the Java 6 docs (+made a few other tweaks).  Had to +1 it though.  a) For linking to both JavaDocs & an article. b) For providing code examples & caveats, but mostly.. c) For *"Go forth and be thread-safe."* :-)

Comment: It is important to note that, while this answer is spot on as far as it goes, *background threads should never attempt to update the GUI directly*. If the background thread needs update something, it needs to schedule the change through Swing's EDT.

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas:

1) Create a `java.util.Timer` that fires periodically, checking the mailbox for messages and updating the GUI using `SwingUtilities#invokeLater`;

2) Create a timer (either `java.util.Timer` or `javax.swing.Timer`) that schedules a `javax.swing.SwingWorker` to both check the mailbox and update the GUI.

3) Create a `Thread` that checks the mailbox, updates the GUI using `SwingUtilities#invokeLater` and sleeps for some time;

I'd use 1 or 2, because you can just stop the timers if you ever need to cancel the task.

Answer (score -1):

Obviously you need to use **EDT** if you need to update the UI after finishing the checkMails() method.

And you are looking for **asynchronous** (other one is synchronous) way.

Certainly you are looking for [SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

According to my knowledge, this is the correct way to do background task for Swing.

```
Runnable checkMail = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            checkMails();
            Thread.sleep(120000); //but this is very naive approach to use sleep, consider using timer ;)
        }
    }
};

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(checkMail);
```

> invokeLater(Runnable doRun): Causes doRun.run() to be executed asynchronously on the AWT event dispatching thread.

and

> invokeAndWait(Runnable doRun): Causes doRun.run() to be executed synchronously on the AWT event dispatching thread.

Comment: invokeLater schedules the Runnable to be executed on the EDT, so this will block the user interface.

Comment: No, its not. Edited the answer to add quote from documentation ;)